# How to make a C# win service app to refer assemblies from a host machine

Tags: c#, windows-installer, gac, assembly-resolution, dllregistration

I am building an agent service in C# to communicate with SCVMM installed on host. To do that the agent refers the following assemblies: Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.dll and Erros.dll etc.

In visual studio dev environment, I have added references to the agent app. When I build in debug/release mode basically I don't the above assemblies to be copied to debug/release directory, since the agent will distributed to customers. Basically agent app communicates with SCVMM, SCVMM must have been installed before installing the agent app.

One thing that I don't understand is how to make the agent service to refer Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.dll etc files that are already existing at `<SCVMM root>/bin` folder.

Comment: Are those assemblies added to the GAC when they are installed on a machine?

Comment: No, Installing SCVMM does not register the assemblies to GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Reference as normal in visual studio and before calling any method in the dll call :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(scvmmroot + "/bin");
```

You could also do it in the `yourapp.exe.config` file (See [Set Custom Path to Referenced DLL's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892492/c-set-custom-path-to-referenced-dlls) ) But as your path isn't relative to the executable that would mean generating the `.config` file in your installer.