# Setup environment variable to find the dlls at runtime with C#

Tags: c#, dll, environment-variables

I use ANTLR for parsing a document, and I need some ANTLR dlls.
For compilation, I can use /lib: to located where the ANTLR dll libraries are located, but when I run the execution binary I got error message.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.1.3.421
54, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3a9cab8f8d22bfb7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specif
ied.
   at Antlr.Examples.LLStar.LLStarApp.Main(String[] args)
```

The error is gone when I copy the ANTLR dll in the same directory where the execution binary is located.

I added the directory where the dlls are located in the path, it still doesn't work. 
How can I setup an environment variable or something to find the dlls? I use Windows 7.

### ADDED

I guess there is no way to use PATH or environment variable to do this, I think GAC is one solution, and [Set Custom Path to Referenced DLL's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892492/c-sharp-set-custom-path-to-referenced-dlls) is the other solution, even though it can find only the sub-directories beneath the directory where the execution binary is located.

Comment: This is a DLL Hell countermeasure.  Copying the DLL locally is the correct way to do it.  Using AppDomain.AssemblyResolve is questionable.

Answer (score 3):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPathProbe`

or

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sndr,resolveEventArgs) =>
{
    if(resolveEventArgs.Name==something){
        return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
    }
    return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) class for this.

Specifically the `GetEnvironmentVariable` and `SetEnvironmentVariable` methods (in this case with the `PATH` environment variable.

Use `GetEnvironmentVariable` to retrieve the current settings, then add your path to the returned string and use `SetEnvironmentVariable` to update it.

---

Of course, you could do all this manually.

Comment: Do I really need to change C# source code to find the dll at runtime? For mono, I just set environment variable to find it.

Comment: @prosseek - No, you don't. Hence my last line about doing it manually... Though you didn't specify what OS you are using - this is slightly different in the different versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void AddEnvironmentPaths(IEnumerable<string> paths)
    {
        var path = new[] { Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? string.Empty };

        string newPath = string.Join(Path.PathSeparator.ToString(), path.Concat(paths).ToArray());

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", newPath);
    }
```