# how to change dll directory in C# project

Tags: c#, dll, directory

I used a dll in my C# project that its Directory is exactly in same location of exe file. so when I install my project, the dll file will be locate in exe Directory.

is there any way that I change dll Directory? for example the dll file locate in this: bin\DLLs. I dont want that user know about my dll easily.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="bin\DLLs" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can change and include the path in config file.

Comment: [stackoverflow: set custom dll path][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892492/c-sharp-set-custom-path-to-referenced-dlls

Comment: @user3840692 I tested that solution but didnt work. do u know why? I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to change dll directory that users cant see them. So I try to load DLL from Embedded Resource. its a good idea that workes for me.

by this way, you can change your exe file with out any related dll.

see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource?msg=4866923#xx4866923xx) for more detailes

Answer (score 2):

You can install your dll's in GAC to "hide them". But it won't hide them from a skilled user.

Comment: Can u explain more? I don't know about GAC