# Unable to resolve issue 'You can only specify the READPAST lock in the READ COMMITTED or REPEATABLE READ isolation levels'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, production-environment

Our client is facing this issue after launching a screen. This screen, on launching, fires a query having READPAST as table hint. This screen used to work without any error but it suddenly started throwing this issue on client side. But we are not able to reproduce this issue on our environment. We haven't released any code change, still our client started facing this issue suddenly. Can anyone help me with this issue?
Is this issue occurring due to any Microsoft update / SQL server update or any other system change?

Comment: I would suggest that, as some point, the connection string details have been changed to not use `READ COMMITTED` or `REPEATABLE READ` as the isolation level.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly indicates that you are in an isolation level **other** than the 2 supported isolation levels as stated in the error messages.
You may try using the *sys.dm_exec_sessions* DMV to get the connection's isolation level.
Another way would be to use Profiler, SQL Trace or Extended Events. If you have no past experience with these tools then using Profiler would be simplest. If you do use Profiler see if you are able filter your trace on a columns such as the ApplicationName, HostName, LoginName etc. in order not to capture too much data (assuming the system is busy).

Comment: We asked our client to check isolation level on production environment, as per their reply isolation level in production is ReadCommitted, which is the one of the isolation levels in error message.

Comment: @Vidhi, did you find the solution? I have the same problem. Tks

Answer (score 0):

This happen due to replication in database server, Check the solution in my answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345478/1594274

Thanks