# Call WPF after build in different folder VSCode 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a solution with 3 projects: 2 WPF applications (WPF_A and WPF_B) and 1 class library.
In my working directory divided into several sections:

PARAM (which contains the .sln)
PROJECT A (which contains WPF_A and WPF_B)
CC (which contains my class library)
My WPF_A calls WPF_B using this line of code:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newform = new WPF_B.MainWindow();
            newform.Show();
        }
```

and it works when I run WPF_A under Visual Studio 2015.

The issue arises when I build in release; I would like WPF_B to be in a subfolder of WPF_A.

```
WPF_A
--CC
----Library.cs
--PROJECT_B
----WPF_B
```

I can build this directory structure, but WPF_A fails to call WPF_B if it is not in the same folder.

How can I configure the project to have a different directory structure after the build?

Comment: When a dll is loaded, various paths are checked in order, <Same Directory><System Directory> etc... obviously a sub folder won't get searched. Instead you could load the dll in code using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1345683/can-i-use-a-dll-in-a-folder-other-than-the-project) method.

Comment: And another method is to use this answer [Set Custom Path to Referenced DLL's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892492/set-custom-path-to-referenced-dlls)

Comment: The second method work pretty well for me, thank you !